# Install batman-adv under Ubuntu to start a mesh network

Tags: networking, mesh

I want to install batman-adv to join a mesh network but I don't find it in the repository

```
apt-cache search batman-adv
```

Is it possible to install it in  Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the packet batman-adv since Ubuntu 12.04.

Install the packet

```
apt-get install batctl bridge-utils
```

then

```
modprobe batman-adv
batctl -v
```

sais for example:

> batctl debian-2011.4.0-2 [batman-adv: 2011.4.0]

(only some versions are compatible)

for example to connect to `batman.kiel.freifunk.net` on `wlan0` with the bssid `02:ca:ff:ee:ba:be`
use [this script](http://freifunk.in-kiel.de/wiki/Eigenen_Rechner_in_das_Freifunk-Netz). that will start a mesh network on your computer.

To get back to normal networking just restart the networkmanager:

```
/etc/init.d/network-manager restart
```

and remove the node from batman (see script)

Comment: I edited the script-url to the Wiki of Freifunk Kiel: http://freifunk.in-kiel.de/wiki/Eigenen_Rechner_in_das_Freifunk-Netz