# How do I install alfred-json on Ubuntu?

Tags: networking

Is there a PPA for the packages, I need to use alfred on ubuntu?

I would like to analyse the Freifunk batman mesh network in Germany/Kiel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install `alfed-json` via the repository:

```
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/draic.list << EOF
deb [arch=amd64] http://debian.draic.info/ wheezy main
deb-src http://debian.draic.info/ wheezy main
EOF
apt-get update
apt-get install libjansson-dev cmake python3-pip fakeroot dpkg-dev build-essential zlib1g-dev pkg-config debhelper
cd /tmp/
apt-get source --allow-unauthenticated alfred-json
cd alfred-json-0.3.1/
dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
dpkg -i ../alfred-json_0.3.1-1_i386.deb
```

install `alfred` and `batadv-vis`:

```
apt-get install quilt
apt-get source --allow-unauthenticated alfred
cd alfred-2014.3.0/
dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
dpkg -i ../alfred_2014.3.0-11_i386.deb
dpkg -i ../batadv-vis_2014.3.0-11_i386.deb
```

Comment: That's a Debian repository - you SHOULD BE CAREFUL with Debian repositories - they can break things

Answer (score 1):

Download it here:

- https://github.com/tcatm/alfred-json
- https://github.com/tcatm/alfred

first install `alfred-json`:

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/tcatm/alfred-json.git
cd alfred-json
sudo apt-get install libjansson-dev cmake
cmake .
make
make install
```

For some examples: see the README in that GIT repository

To use alfred you need to install batman with the packet

```
sudo apt-get install batctl
```

then

```
sudo  modprobe batman-adv
```

and install `alfred` itself:

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/tcatm/alfred.git
cd alfred
make
make install
```

see [Install batman-adv under Ubuntu to start a mesh network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205337/how-do-i-install-batman-adv-under-ubuntu-12-04-to-start-a-mesh-network?rq=1)

You can also create the PPA:  `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/90-debian.draic.info.list`

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://debian.draic.info/ wheezy main
deb-src http://debian.draic.info/ wheezy main
```

---

To install the `alfred` daemon (A.L.F.R.E.D - Almighty Lightweight Fact Remote Exchange Daemon) and `batadv-vis`:

```
cd /tmp/
wget https://github.com/rubo77/alfred-repository/blob/master/alfred_2014.3.0-11_i386.deb?raw=true
sudo dpkg -i alfred_2014.3.0-11_i386.deb
wget https://github.com/rubo77/alfred-repository/blob/master/batadv-vis_2014.3.0-11_i386.deb?raw=true
sudo dpkg -i batadv-vis_2014.3.0-11_i386.deb
```